# How to set the first part of a split input to the second part (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, list, input

```
var1 = "plzHalp"
cmd = input("> ")
subcmd = cmd.split(" ")
if subcmd[0] == "set" and subcmd[1] in setL:
    secondOp = subcmd[1]
    cmdVar = subcmd[2]
    eval(subcmd[1]) = subcmd[2]
    print("[Set",secondOp,"==>",cmdVar)
```

What I want this to do, is assign the second part of the subcommand (subcmd[1]) and change a pre-made variable to the third part (subcmd[2]).
E.g. if the command is "set var1 fixedYay" then var1 would then be equal to "fixedYay".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to replace `eval(subcmd[1])` with `globals()[subcmd[1]]`. See the below example and read up on the globals() and locals() functions.

```
C:\Users\nagul>python                                                                                 
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:16:59) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32        
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                
>>> var1='plzHalp'                                                                                    
>>> var1_str='var1'                                                                                   
>>> print(globals()[var1_str])                                                                        
plzHalp                                                                                               
>>> globals()[var1_str]='fixedYay'                                                                    
>>> print(var1)                                                                                       
fixedYay                                                                                              
>>>
```